# miniDLNA + OpenVPN, VLC don't see the dlna

Tags: vlc-media-player, openvpn, dlna

Here's my conf :

raspberry pi with an openvpn server and a minidlna server.

I run two instance of minidlna : one listening the local network, the instance which I access from inside the network, and one listening the vpn address (10.8.0.1) which I access from outside, when I'm connected to the openvpn server.

Here's the point : when I'm connected on my phone to openvpn, I can see the dlna server and stream from it without any troubles. When I'm connected on my computer to openvpn, I can't see the dlna server (I'm using VLC, "UPnP discover").

Everything works fine when I'm inside my local network.

Anyone has an idea why VLC doesn't see the DLNA ?

Thanks !

EDIT : The route table from my mac

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
0/1                10.8.0.5           UGSc           11        0   utun0
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc            4        0     en1
10.8/24            10.8.0.5           UGSc            0        0   utun0
10.8.0.1/32        10.8.0.5           UGSc            0        0   utun0
10.8.0.5           10.8.0.6           UHr            23       54   utun0
82.120.45.26/32    192.168.1.1        UGSc            1        0     en1
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             19   295490     lo0
128.0/1            10.8.0.5           UGSc            7        0   utun0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
192.168.1          link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
192.168.1.1/32     link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
192.168.1.1        24:95:4:c4:b8:18   UHLWIir         4     9300     en1   1194
192.168.1.65/32    link#5             UCS             1        0     en1
192.168.1.65       20:c9:d0:d4:97:31  UHLWI           0        1     lo0
192.168.1.110/32   10.8.0.5           UGSc            0        0   utun0
192.168.1.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       11     en1
```

From my phone :

```
Destination        Gateway            Genmask        Flags      MSS        Window      irtt        Iface
0.0.0.0            192.168.1.1        0.0.0.0        UG         378                  0           0           wlan0
10.8.0.8           0.0.0.0            255.255.255.252U          0                  0           0           tun0
192.168.1.0        0.0.0.0            255.255.255.0  U          378                  0           0           wlan0
```

EDIT2 : The trouble really comes from my computer configuration : I used my phone as a modem and shared my cellular connection with my computer. I still can't see my minidlna with VLC.

Comment: Can you post the routing tables of the phone and of the pc?

Comment: Do you know can I find them ? My phone is an Android LG G3 (cyanogen), my computer is a macbook OS 10.10

Comment: On Mac, `netstat -rn -f inet`; on android, install `netstat` from PlayStore.

Comment: Both have been taken when you are off the VPN. Instead, they should have been taken when you are connected to the VPN.

Comment: My bad... I corrected it.